# Android: Converted Tensorflow 2.0 SavedModel to TFLite problem with confidence value

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Hello I've converted a SavedModel file to TFLite file after using transfer learning technique on TFHub MobileNet module (SavedModel TF2.0) using this source code https://gist.github.com/mypapit/e3b26787c95caf840e5c16a79327d443 and I tried running it on Tensorflow for Poet sample Android application

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKSOH.png)

The resulting Android app seems to be able to classify my retrained classes correctly. However, the accuracy is way off (like ridiculously off!), you can refer to the screenshot.

Normally, the accuracy supposedly to be in the range of 0.000 to 1.000. But with my converted TFLite model, the accuracy range varies wildly from -400 to 500.00++

FYI I've already tinker with IMAGE_MEAN and IMAGE_STD value (255f,0f) and (127.5f, 127.5f), but to no avail.

can somebody help me?

The standard TensorFlow for Poets Android source code which I used to test the model is here: https://gist.github.com/mypapit/f7a9b54ee502f02ca72da3f972d25fb9

The converted TFLite file is here:https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmVw1Hsqu0-CguVlKyCNE0W-NzODEg?e=LkjBXl
and its labelmap is here: https://gist.github.com/mypapit/56845dde0c47e21d0e18ec86d25a3ff2

I've noticed that this only happened when I use tfhub module (TF2.0 SavedModel) with Tensorflow 2.x, it does not happened when I use tfhub module with Tensorflow 1.14

I'm already at my wits end, can somebody help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing last softmax layer which makes sum of all the label outputs to be 1.

https://medium.com/data-science-bootcamp/understand-the-softmax-function-in-minutes-f3a59641e86d

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your dataset, I tried your model with flower dataset and converted the model as in your code and then deployed on Android device using Android studio. I had used TFLite app and replaced assets folder with the `*.tflite` and 'labels.txt`. Accuracy is very good. Please check the images below. Based on this, I can surely tell root-cause is not your model or TFLite conversion. Root-cause may be your data (preprocessing of images) or Android part of the code. Please check the code implementation [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Flowers_tf_lite_Keras_Hub_Layer.ipynb)

[image: Andriod Studio]

[image]